How to visually show the calendar of shifts for a worker?
Sorry for my dumb question, but I never worked on UI side before for complex projects.
I'm developing a PHP/JavaScript application for the school of my daughter and I have a table with the information about shifts for workers.
Example of data for worker John Doe:



date
name




08/20/24
John Doe


09/13/24
John Doe


11/08/24
John Doe


02/19/25
John Doe


04/02/25
John Doe



I'd like to show in a graph the distribution of his shifts alogn the whole school year.
I'm going to use chart.js if that matters.
My first thought is a bar graph, with the dates on the X-axis and just a "rectangle" whenever his has a shift (since on the Y-axis the only value is 0 if he has no shifts that day or 1 if his has).
Does it make sense?
May you give me an example how would you make the graph?
The goal is to understand at first sight how many shift a worker has and most important how they are distributed along the whole year.
UPDATE
This is a raw graph I've made with real data:


The graph is not a great solution for this because your Y axis is binary - either there's a shift, or there isn't one, he can't have multiple shifts on the same day, or half a shift. So there's no need for the "height" dimension of the graph.
It might begin to make sense if you start aggregating the data - if you switch the resolution to "weeks" or "months" instead of "days" - then he might have 5 shifts on the week of Oct 31st, and only 2 the following week.
There are two things you need to know before you address this. One is how many shifts they're likely to have per year. The other is the exact use case - what do they actually want to see and why. If they don't have many shifts - say just a couple shifts a month or less - then the best format is probably the one that you already used, meaning the table. There's no need to visualize anything, just list the dates in a single column. The visualization doesn't add any value in this case and only makes things more complicated.
If it's important for them to quickly see how many shifts they've got each month /week and to be able to quickly compare this - then a visualization might be appropriate, and your column chart is a good solution (assuming there's more than one shift per month/week).
Finally, if you absolutely must have a visualization even on the current scale, remember that the most intuitive way to display dates is by using a calendar format, so you can just take a calendar and mark the relevant days.

Thanks for the hints. Some more information: the shifts are in range 4..6 per year (the graph is on real data). I'm going to add the graph since it talks about how regularly are distributed along the year, without make calculations from the tables or a calendar.

@Mark If you believe that what interests them is the distribution, then that's what you should display :). 12 months or 50 weeks with a real column chart where the height shows the number of shifts. If you leave it on a daily resolution level, it still requires them to calculate, and uses a chart that's not really appropriate for this task, since it doesn't emphasize the breakdown into months/weeks.

Got it! Just to avoid any misunderstanding due to the language barrier: for "distribution" I mean how evenly spaced the shifts are.
